# AWS IOT Greengrass x509: certificate signed by unknown authority MQTT[client] Failed to connect to a broker

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I am trying to deploy a greengrass group but the deployment goes on (in progress). The errors which im facing are:

1. "MQTT client is failed to connect to a broker"
2. MQTT[client]   x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
3. Requested certificate load [file:///greengrass/certs/a9029bd10f.cert.pem] with error: []
4. [INFO]-No proxy URL found.
5. Requested certificate load [file:///greengrass/certs/root.ca.pem] with error: []
   I think these are which is creating a problem in deployment. Below is the `runtime.log`. I am using AWS IOT Greengrass on Windows 10. Please help me.

```
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.036Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested certificate load [file:///greengrass/certs/root.ca.pem] with error: [<nil>]
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.037Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested key load [file:///greengrass/certs/a9029bd10f.private.key] with error: [<nil>]
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.038Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested certificate load 
[file:///greengrass/certs/a9029bd10f.cert.pem] with error: [<nil>]
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.038Z][INFO]-Started Deployment Agent to listen for updates.
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.038Z][INFO]-Connecting with MQTT.  {"endpoint": "a2fhwgkt3lz1ij-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883", "clientId": "myproject_Core"}
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.038Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "YNTA", "clientId": "myproject_Core"}
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.038Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.038Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.038Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.648Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[2020-01-18T04:49:58.648Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker
```

Comment: Please, explain in detail what you're trying to achieve here!

Comment: Im trying to deploye a simple greengrass but it goes on "in progress". the error which im facing is "MQTT   x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"                            
"MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker". Please help me in resolving the certificates issue and establishing the MQTT connection. i already share the runtime. log above.

Comment: When asking questions you should provide as much details as possible and state the your goal at the end of the post. You should edit your post.

Comment: Sorry, i have just updated. please help me in finding a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you need to update your AWS client or AMI image or both. Have a look [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/grove-sensors-aws-greengrass-group-and-device-to-cloud-communication) or [here](https://medium.com/tensoriot/aws-greengrass-on-raspberry-pi-creating-core-and-node-devices-707a38452293)

Comment: Thanks i have the ATS endpoints issues. I download the certificates by opening  a web browser, open the Amazon Root CA 1 certificate. Save the document as root.ca.pem in the C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\certs directory, which contains the decompressed certificates. but this time got this error.  [ERROR]-Failed to unmount tmpfs       {"path": "/greengrass/ggc/packages/1.10.0/dns", "errorString": "failed to umount with args dest=\"/greengrass/ggc/packages/1.10.0/dns\" flags=\"0\": operation not permitted"}